# When GNU parallel exit，my program also fail

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnu-parallel

I am using GNU `parallel` to run a bash function. The function just contains the bash script to restart my program. At first, the restart is ok, but when `parallel` exits, my program also fails. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash

function_A () {
        local module=$1
        set -x
        cd /dir/${module}/;sh stop_${module}.sh;sh start_${module}.sh;sleep 10
}
export -f function_A

parallel --tag --onall --env function_A -S my_host function_A ::: my_program
```

**Output from ps:**

```
root     12967  0.0  0.0  65960  1152 pts/1    Ss+  16:30   0:00 bash -c echo $SHELL | egrep "/t?csh" > /dev/null && echo CSH/TCSH DO NOT SUPPORT newlines IN VARIABLES/FUNCTIONS && exec false;? eval `echo $SHELL | grep "/t\{0,1\}csh" > /dev/null  && echo setenv PARALLEL_SEQ 1\;  setenv PARALLEL_PID 6431  || echo PARALLEL_SEQ=1\;export PARALLEL_SEQ\;  PARALLEL_PID=6431\;export PARALLEL_PID` ; tty >/dev/null && stty isig -onlcr -echo;echo $SHELL | grep "/t\{0,1\}csh" > /dev/null && setenv function_A \(\)\ \{\ \ local\ module=\$1\;"?"\ set\ -x\;"?"\ cd\ /dir/\$\{module\}/\;"?"\ sh\ test.sh\;"?"\ sleep\ 10"?"\} || export function_A=\(\)\ \{\ \ local\ module=\$1\;"?"\ set\ -x\;"?"\ cd\ /dir/\$\{module\}/\;"?"\ sh\ test.sh\;"?"\ sleep\ 10"?"\} && eval function_A"$function_A";function_A my_program
```

Comment: Not passing any args to function so `$1` will be empty. Also post the error in the question

Comment: But my_program is $1.when parallel running,my_program start ok.when parallel stop,my_program also fail,why?

Comment: What do you mean the program also fails? Any error message you could share?

Comment: My program has already received requests during sleep 10. But after sleep 10 ,then parallel exit,I can not find my_program in ps commond.

Comment: The script to restart your program needs to run it in a new session. The same thing will happen if you start it from a normal shell and then logout.

Comment: What is the output of `parallel -vv ....` What happens when you run that manually? What is your login shell on `my_host`?

Comment: My login shell is BASH on my_host.my start script contain sudo -u.I do not whether have problems

Comment: How to make sure the script to run in a new session?

Comment: I find the reason.The restart script contains backupground(&),but I can not remove the &，because I will make sure my_program run normally.What can I do?

Comment: Instead of `foo &` try `(foo &)`

Comment: (foo &) Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, you want to start a daemon on the remote machine, and when GNU Parallel exits, the daemon should continue running.

For that you should use a tool that allows a command to continue even after you logout. I know of 3 such tools:

```
nohup
screen
tmux
```

So use these in your function:

```
    cd /dir/${module}/;nohup sh stop_${module}.sh;nohup sh start_${module}.sh;sleep 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `nohup sh "start_${module}.sh" &`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function_A () {
        local module=$1
        set -x
        cd "/dir/${module}/"
        sh "stop_${module}.sh"
        nohup sh "start_${module}.sh" &
        sleep 10
}
export -f function_A

parallel --tag --onall --env function_A -S my_host function_A ::: my_program
```

The `nohup` command will cause the underlying script to not exit when the shell exits, for example, during a logout. '&' will immediately background the process. Also, make sure your `"start_${module}.sh"` works non-interactively; for example, try running it as `sh -c 'sh start_${module}.sh'`) to make sure it works.